# "Error: Cache-only enabled but no cache for XXX" when using dnf as non-root

Tags: fedora, repository, cache, dnf

On Fedora I have enabled a third-party repository for a non-free software (SoftMaker).
When I run dnf commands **as root** (such as `sudo dnf search -C vim`), everything works fine. However, when I run the same command as non-root, I get the following error:

```
> dnf search -C vim
SoftMaker Office Repository                                16 kB/s | 991  B     00:00
Importing GPG key 0xAA3E7F5E:
 Userid     : "SoftMaker repository (GPG key for signing files) <info@softmaker.com>"
 Fingerprint: CC7D 2EDF 4808 EFFA 0E00 FC72 3413 DA98 AA3E 7F5E
 From       : http://shop.softmaker.com/repo/linux-repo-public.key
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Error: Cache-only enabled but no cache for 'SoftMaker_Office_Repository'
```

The gpg key import question aris every time, even though I answered `y` before.
I imported the key via `sudo rpmkeys --import linux-repo-public.key`, but it did not help.

**So: Is there anything I can do to create the cache for the user (or is it a problem from the repository provider)?**

The corresponding repo file `/etc/yum.repos.d/softmaker.repo` looks like this:

```
[SoftMaker_Office_Repository]
name=SoftMaker Office Repository
enabled=1
baseurl=http://shop.softmaker.com/repo/rpm
path=/
type=rpm-md
keeppackages=0
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://shop.softmaker.com/repo/linux-repo-public.key
enabled_metadata=0
```

(The unfortunate side effect is, that Gnome-Software does not work at all due to this...)

Comment: No idea what the issue is but dnf is meant to be used under root/sudo, so I'm curious why you're trying to solve an issue you've yourself created.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov no, `dnf` supports many operations run as regular users (especially `search` which isn’t supposed to change anything); and it integrates with PolicyKit so even for operations requiring root privileges, starting it as a regular user is fine.

Comment: @StephenKitt `dnf search` under a regular user cannot use/update the system-wide cache which makes using it kinda counter-productive as it needs to download all the repos to `/var/tmp/dnf-$user-$random`. Besides the OP is specifically talking about installing a package the very task which is meant to be run under root/sudo.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov it may be counter-productive, but that doesn’t mean that “dnf is meant to be used under root/sudo” or that the OP is “trying to solve an issue [they themselves] created”. `dnf search -C vim` doesn’t install a package.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov an example for the behaviour use is Gnome-Software. The user is supposed to search for packages as he likes but only has to authenticate as a user when he wants to install something.  I'd be happy if the search would use the system cache in a read-only manner, but this is not the case.

Comment: Gnome-Software and other GUI software managers for Fedora don't use `dnf`  directly per se, they use its APIs. :-)

Comment: `type=rpm-md` is what might be causing issues for you because it's a repository format invented by OpenSUSE and I'm not exactly sure it works the same way as "classic" Fedora repositories.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov you mean on the host's/repository side? Because the setting itself does not change this behaviour...

Comment: *you mean on the host's/repository side?* Yes, exactly

Answer (score -1):

The message

```
Cache-only enabled but no cache for
```

comes from `libdnf:Repo.cpp`:

```c
if (syncStrategy == SyncStrategy::ONLY_CACHE)
```

So it just quits, if it had gone on it will do the fetch.

Question is how did `ONLY_CACHE` occur, as not using `-C` or `--cacheonly`,
or where the frig it might be getting it from?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/428569)

Comment: I’m not saying the information isn’t useful; it’s in the wrong place. Please [suggest an edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/605242/edit) to the question, adding the contents of your post.